# Parameter validateset wildcard

Tags: powershell

Is it possible to make a Paramater validateset work with a wildcard?

I would want on the `*` places to accept 0-100.

```
param
  (
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$True)]
    [validateset("6.1.*.*")]
    [string]$variable
  )
```

Error message:

> Cannot validate argument on parameter 'variable'. The argument "6.1.1.0" does not belong to the set "6.1.*.*" specified by the ValidateSet attribute. Supply an argument that is in the set and then try the command again.
>           + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
>           + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationError

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since it looks like you're looking to validate a *version*, you may want to declare the parameter of the type `[version]` and use the `ValidateScript` attribute to validate the value rather than using string matching:

```
function Test-Version {
  param(
    [ValidateScript({
        $_.Major -eq '6' -and 
        $_.Minor -eq '1' -and
        $_.Build -in (0..100) -and
        $_.Revision -in (0..100) -or 
        $(throw 'Wrong Version')
      })]
    [version]$Version
  )    
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed!

Answer (score 4):

No, that's what `[ValidatePattern()]` is for:

```
param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$True)]
    [ValidatePattern('6\.1\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}')]
    [string]$variable
)
```

It takes a regular expression as the parameter.

`[ValidateSet()]` is meant to be used if there is a small, constant set of values. PowerShell also provides autocompletion for these. For example:

```
[ValidateSet('Windows', 'Mac', 'Linux')
$OperatingSystem
```

See [this article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms714432(v=vs.85).aspx) for more parameter validation attributes.